# TSQL Like and Not like usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, sql-server-2016

I have links data as follows :

```
Data
www.example.com/
www.example.com/someotherpath/
www.example.com/someotherpath/included
www.example.com/someexclusivepath/
www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded/
www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded
```

I am trying to write a Like condition which should just give me 4 results from above :

```
www.example.com/
www.example.com/someotherpath/
www.example.com/someotherpath/included
www.example.com/someexclusivepath/
```

If I do a Like and not like :

```
%www.example.com/%' AND Not like '%www.example.com/someexclusivepath/%'
```

This will exclude some links from above as well and the result would be :

```
www.example.com/
www.example.com/someotherpath/
www.example.com/someotherpath/included
```

How do I get the expected result?

**UPDATE :**

Example :

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (link varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('www.example.com/'),
('www.example.com/someotherpath/'),
('www.example.com/someotherpath/included'),
('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/'),('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded/'),
('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded')

SELECT * FROM @tbl

SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE link like '%www.example.com/%' AND Link Not like '%www.example.com/someexclusivepath/%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (link varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('www.example.com/'),
('www.example.com/someotherpath/'),
('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/'), 
('www.example.com/someotherpath/included'),    
('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded/'),
('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded')

SELECT * FROM @tbl
     WHERE (link like '%/%' or link like '%/%/') 
     and (link not like '%/%/[a-z]%' or link like '%/%/included')
```

See it in action [here](http://rextester.com/live/NFOYF76514).

Comment: I missed one more item : www.domain.com/someotherpath/included

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi and here you go.

Answer (score 0):

If they always start the same, and they end with a '/' symbol, you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (link varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('www.example.com/'),('www.example.com/someotherpath/'),('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/'),('www.example.com/someexclusivepath/AnyPathHereShouldBeExcluded/')
SELECT * FROM @tbl

SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE Link Not like 'www.example.com/someexclusivepath/%/'
```

Comment: What if I want to exclude both that end with a slash and the one that does not for 'someexclusivepath' ?

Comment: I have updated the example to include one without a trailing slash :(

Comment: Is this "someexlcusivepath" the only one? Such as domain.com/abc? or are there multiple such as domain.com/abc1, domain.com/abc2?

Comment: that is the only one